# How can i pass the variable value from one file of vuejs script setup to another file of vuejs template

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to send text from variable. I am writing all my text in one script setup using different variables and want to use these variable in the template section of another vue3js file in another folder

I tried that but didn't worked. I searched and followed their steps but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to pass the value from one component to another component,

1. Using props to share data from parent to child,
2. Emitting custom events to share data from child to parent,
3. Using Vuex to create an app-level shared state

Share the code which you tried and it will be easier to understand what exactly you need.

Comment: I was doing this way
filepath = '/componenst/Home/LandingView.vue' 
<script setup>
var Landing = "This is landing page";
</script>
<template>
    <h1>{{Landing}}</h1>
</template>
<style scoped>
</style>

Comment: I wanted to do another way shown below. Put all my variable in one file and access from that file. So, it will be easier to edit text in future.

filepath = '/comonents/TextFile.vue'
<script setup>
var Landing = "This is landing page";
</script>
<template>
</template>
<style>
</style>

filepath = '/componenst/Home/LandingView.vue' 
<script setup>
import TextFile from './components/TextFile.vue'
</script>

<template>
    <h1>{{Landing}}</h1>
</template>
<style scoped></style>

Comment: is it possible to do this way??? I tried but it shows TextFile is imported but its value isn't used.  And i tried to share my code during posting my question but it always shows error of format not corrected even after i put the indent in my codes

Comment: You should pass it as props only. That will be the easier way. Try this - https://tutorialslink.com/Articles/How-To-Pass-Data-Between-Components-In-Vuejs/1774